# Problems sending mail to gmail with nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, email, nodemailer

I'm trying to add a contact form in my website using nodemailer.
With plain-text, the email was sent (with the cmd node server.js), but since I have added a form in my html and tried to send the "req.bodies" using a route, it doesn't work anymore and I have the following error : Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN".

Here are my codes :

**Index.js**

```
    var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

/* GET home page. */
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
res.render("index", { title: "Express" });
});

router.post("/send-email", async function (req, res, next) {
"use strict";
var email = req.body.email;
var name = req.body.name;
var message = req.body.message;

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  // host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  service: "gmail",
  // secure : false,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL,
    pass: process.env.PASSWORD,
  },
});

console.log("message :", req.body.message, "email :", req.body.email);
// send mail with defined transport object
var mailOptions = {
  from: email,
  to: process.env.EMAIL,
  subject: "Nouveau mail contact de " + name, // Subject line
  text: name + "0102030405" + message,
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const port = 3000;

require("dotenv").config();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Server running on ${port}`);
});

app.use("/index", require("./routes/index"));

// let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
//   service: "gmail",
//   auth: {
//     user: process.env.EMAIL,
//     pass: process.env.PASSWORD,
//   },
// });

// let mailOptions = {
//   from: '"Fred Foo " <process.env.EMAIL>', // sender address
//   to: "process.env.EMAIL", // list of receivers
//   subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
//   text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
//   html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body
// };

// transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, data) {
//   if (err) {
//     console.log("Error Occurs");
//   } else {
//     console.log("Email sent !!");
//   }
// });
```

**html**

```
<form action="/send-email" method="POST">
    Your Name:
    <input type="text" name="name">
    Email Address:
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    Message:
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Body-Parser doesn't seem to work because it is strikeout.
“less secure” apps is enabled on my gmail account

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Google not allow smtp clients by default, You need to allow the SMTP in the account settings, and use an "application password" https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : I think it's because it doesn't recognize my process.env because when I directly write them, it works.

I put my file .env in the same directory but it still does not recognize them.